Can we get a better complexity than O(n) for cumulative sum while using multithreading?
I'm new to multithreading algorithms and I'm trying do recode cumulative sum function to get a better complexity than O(n).
Have you any hint? Or we can't get better than O(n)?
I tried to use divide and conquer method but didn't get the execpted result. Tried with some parrallel loop but not conclusive too.
Thank's for your help

Are you asking how to add n numbers together into one sum in less than O(n) time?

No, you have to see every number to sum every number that is O(n).

Unless you know the input numbers have patterns  e.g. (N={1,2,3,4....}) or N={1,4,9,16 ....} there is no way to do better than O(n).

Well, very approximately speaking, if you have k cores and a very parallelizable problem (which this is), then you ought to be able to divide your time taken by k with parallelism.
Problem is, k is fixed, while n isn't. With k being constant, O(n/k) is the same thing as O(n). It'll go faster, but not asymptotically faster.
In abstract principle, your divide-and-conquer algorithm might well run in O(log(n)) time, but it would require O(n) processors to do so.
Because k is fixed, multithreading an algorithm will never improve its asymptotic time, only the constant factors. Your parallel implementation might finish in one tenth the time or one twentieth the time the single-threaded implementation does, but not in log of the time or square root of the time.

Who's to say k is fixed while n isn't? They're both parameters.

The number of physical cores is generally fixed at runtime, unless you dedicated some cores to buying, unboxing and hot-plugging new CPUs on the fly

@Useless In complexity theory you abstract away over details (let's not forget we're completely ignoring any multiplicative constant here) and assume a model of computation. There are models of computation that model something other than a single modern CPU processor, e.g. distributed or biological/neural systems, where the number of processors can scale immensely.

The number of cores at runtime is not fixed in the cloud. Of course that introduces significant overhead in overall resources required and cost.

Big O notation is generally used for the asymptotic complexity as N tends towards infinity. Even the cloud doesn't have an unbounded number of processors, so we can choose a constant upper bound and then ignore it just like every other constant value as N -> ∞

The original draft of my answer did include brief discussion of parallel random access machines, but I decided that this tangent would not be useful to OP.

Wikipedia contains several parallel prefix sum algorithms, including one which runs in O(n log n / k) time if you have k parallel processors, which means the overall process can be O(log n) if you have n processors.

You can't have n processors if you're taking the limit as n -> ∞. If you want to take the limit as n approaches some finite number, that's big omega notation instead.

@Useless Why are you arbitrarily deciding that scaling data to infinity is perfectly valid, but scaling processors to infinity is not?

"Scaling to infinity" is not what taking a limit means. Big-O notation is defined in terms of the limit as n -> ∞. It's perhaps not always the most pertinent or interesting characteristic, but that's the definition nonetheless. You can absolutely claim that for large enough k, your measure is more useful. That isn't a strong enough reason to re-define big-O notation though.

@Useless I'm not redefining anything. You are confused about what big-O or big-Omega is.

"which means the overall process can be O(log n) if you have n processors" - only works if you take the limit as both k and n increase without bound, which is completely different to the definition of O(log n).

@Useless That's just me being informal, by "if you have n processors" I meant "if you have an equal number of processors to the amount of data", which can be relaxed to include an arbitrary constant factor as well, e.g. 1GB per processor.
